HibernateJpaConfiguration.class: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory;
Getting below error while running spring application
spring boot version - 3.2.6
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 out of bounds for length 2
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1788) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:205) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:952) ~[spring-context-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624) ~[spring-context-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.6.jar:3.2.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.2.6.jar:3.2.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.2.6.jar:3.2.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335) ~[spring-boot-3.2.6.jar:3.2.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1363) ~[spring-boot-3.2.6.jar:3.2.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1352) ~[spring-boot-3.2.6.jar:3.2.6]
    at ai.fintaar.workflowapi.WorkFlowApiApplication.main(WorkFlowApiApplication.java:17) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.2.6.jar:3.2.6]
Caused by: jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 out of bounds for length 2
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:421) ~[spring-orm-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:366) ~[spring-orm-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1835) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1784) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 out of bounds for length 2
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.SelectableMappingsImpl.getSelectable(SelectableMappingsImpl.java:154) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.8.Final.jar:6.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.AbstractEmbeddableMapping.getSelectable(AbstractEmbeddableMapping.java:525) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.8.Final.jar:6.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.AbstractEmbeddableMapping.getJdbcMapping(AbstractEmbeddableMapping.java:553) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.8.Final.jar:6.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.EmbeddableValuedModelPart.getJdbcMapping(EmbeddableValuedModelPart.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.8.Final.jar:6.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.SelectableConsumer$MutableSelectableMapping.getJdbcMapping(SelectableConsumer.java:84) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.8.Final.jar:6.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.lambda$buildTableMappings$9(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3561) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.8.Final.jar:6.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.SelectableConsumer$MutableSelectableMapping.forEach(SelectableConsumer.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.8.Final.jar:6.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.SelectableConsumer.accept(SelectableConsumer.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.8.Final.jar:6.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.lambda$visitMutabilityOrderedTables$2(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:722) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.8.Final.jar:6.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.lambda$buildTableMappings$10(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3555) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.8.Final.jar:6.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.visitMutabilityOrderedTables(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:719) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.8.Final.jar:6.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.buildTableMappings(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3548) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.8.Final.jar:6.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.doLateInit(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3424) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.8.Final.jar:6.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.postInstantiate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3702) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.8.Final.jar:6.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.finishInitialization(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:201) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.8.Final.jar:6.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.initializeMappingModel(SessionFactoryImpl.java:364) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.8.Final.jar:6.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:293) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.8.Final.jar:6.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:450) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.8.Final.jar:6.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1507) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.8.Final.jar:6.4.8.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:75) ~[spring-orm-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    ... 24 common frames omitted

spring boot application not running

Possible to share a minimal reproducible example for it?
